# Why is only one data displayed in LineChart?

Tags: jasper-reports

I got all the Reportstuff working, get a PDF generated and redirected as servlet response.

The Report opens up and the data I pass is there (tested with textfields...data is there). When I try to display the data in a line chart, it just shows one data point. I have grouped the chart on the 'day' data, as i want to have a new chart for every day (which also works, as there are 31 charts for my 31 days in testdata.

Plus I have multiple lines to display, bound by the 'type' data. So I want four lines on every diagram: the data itself (type=1), the min-value (type=2), the average value(type=3) and the max-value (type=3). But it just won't work...Where is my mistake?

Here's the code:

## JasperReport:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jasper_report_template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="c5395651-075a-4d6a-a971-d283cab77f63">
    <parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Author" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="day" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[day]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="type" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[type]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="time" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[time]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="kwh" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[kwh]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <sortField name="day"/>
    <sortField name="type"/>
    <group name="DayGroup" minHeightToStartNewPage="60">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{day}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="210" splitType="Stretch">
                <lineChart>
                    <chart evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="DayGroup">
                        <reportElement x="-20" y="10" width="560" height="200" uuid="9abe6b47-1c6f-4bd0-a684-abf9e91b4adc"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Group" resetGroup="DayGroup" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="DayGroup"/>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{type}]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{kwh}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <linePlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <categoryAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </categoryAxisFormat>
                        <valueAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </valueAxisFormat>
                    </linePlot>
                </lineChart>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

## Servlet:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrbcds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(BasicDataHandler.getInstance().getThatBeanList());

            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/");
            JasperReport jasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path+ "/template_all_month_line_graph.jrxml");
            JasperPrint jasPrint; 
            jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasReport, null, jrbcds);
            ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasPrint, sos);
```

## BasicDataHandler:

```
package sc2pdf.datahandlers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import sc2pdf.datasets.DailyDataSet;
import sc2pdf.javabeans.DataObject;

public class BasicDataHandler {

    private static BasicDataHandler myself=null;
    private Map<Integer, DailyDataSet> data = null;
    private Map<Integer, DailyDataSet> min_data = null;
    private Map<Integer, DailyDataSet> avg_data = null;
    private Map<Integer, DailyDataSet> max_data = null;


    public BasicDataHandler() {

        data = new HashMap<Integer, DailyDataSet>();        //holds all the real data values; key: DAY_OF_MONTH; value DailyDataSet for every day of month
        min_data = new HashMap<Integer, DailyDataSet>();    //holds all the min data values; key: DAY_OF_WEEK; value DailyDataSet for every day of week
        avg_data = new HashMap<Integer, DailyDataSet>();    //holds all the average data values; key: DAY_OF_WEEK; value DailyDataSet for every day of week
        max_data = new HashMap<Integer, DailyDataSet>();    //holds all the max data values; key: DAY_OF_WEEK; value DailyDataSet for every day of week

    }

    public static BasicDataHandler getInstance() {

        if (myself == null) {
                myself = new BasicDataHandler();
        }
        return myself;
    }

    private void registerDailyDataSet(DailyDataSet ds) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(ds.getDay());
        Integer tmp = new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        data.put(tmp, ds);

    }

    private void registerCalcValueMinDailyDataSet(DailyDataSet ds) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(ds.getDay());
        Integer tmp = new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

        min_data.put(tmp, ds);

    }

    private void registerCalcValueAvgDailyDataSet(DailyDataSet ds) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(ds.getDay());
        Integer tmp = new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

        avg_data.put(tmp, ds);

    }

    private void registerCalcValueMaxDailyDataSet(DailyDataSet ds) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(ds.getDay());
        Integer tmp = new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

        max_data.put(tmp, ds);

    }


    public void registerDataObject(DataObject dob) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dob.getTimeAsDate());
        Integer key = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DailyDataSet ds = data.get(key);
        if(ds == null) {
            registerDailyDataSet(new DailyDataSet(dob.getTimeAsDate()));
            ds = data.get(key);
        }
        ds.addDataObject(dob);

        Integer keyCalcValues = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        ds = min_data.get(keyCalcValues);

        DataObject t;

        if(ds == null) {
            registerCalcValueMinDailyDataSet(new DailyDataSet(dob.getTimeAsDate()));
            ds = min_data.get(keyCalcValues);
            ds.addDataObject(new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_MIN));
        }else{
             t = ds.getDataObjectByWeekday(dob.getTimeAsDate());
            if(t==null) {
                t=new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_MIN);
                ds.addDataObject(t);
            }
            if(t.getKwh()>dob.getKwh())
                t.setKwh(dob.getKwh());
        }

        ds = avg_data.get(keyCalcValues);

        if(ds == null) {
            registerCalcValueAvgDailyDataSet(new DailyDataSet(dob.getTimeAsDate()));
            ds = avg_data.get(keyCalcValues);
            ds.addDataObject(new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_AVG));
        }else{
            t = ds.getDataObjectByWeekday(dob.getTimeAsDate());
            if(t==null) {
                t=new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_AVG);
                ds.addDataObject(t);
            }
            if(t.getKwh()>dob.getKwh())
                t.setKwh(dob.getKwh());
        }

        ds = max_data.get(keyCalcValues);

        if(ds == null) {
            registerCalcValueMaxDailyDataSet(new DailyDataSet(dob.getTimeAsDate()));
            ds = max_data.get(keyCalcValues);
            ds.addDataObject(new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_MAX));
        }else{
            t = ds.getDataObjectByWeekday(dob.getTimeAsDate());
            if(t==null) {
                t=new DataObject(dob.getTimeAsDate(),dob.getKwh(),DataObject.TYPE_MAX);
                ds.addDataObject(t);
            }
            if(t.getKwh()<dob.getKwh())
                t.setKwh(dob.getKwh());
        }

    }

    public List<DataObject> getThatBeanList() {

        List<DataObject> rl = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

        Iterator<Integer> iter = data.keySet().iterator();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Integer keyToDo = iter.next();

            DailyDataSet dds = data.get(keyToDo);

            rl.addAll(dds.getData());

            c.setTime(dds.getDay());

            Integer dayKey = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            DailyDataSet dsmin = min_data.get(dayKey);

            rl.addAll(dsmin.getData());

            DailyDataSet dsavg = avg_data.get(dayKey);

            rl.addAll(dsavg.getData());

            DailyDataSet dsmax = max_data.get(dayKey);

            rl.addAll(dsmax.getData());

        }

        return rl;
    }
}
```

## DailyDataSet:

```
package sc2pdf.datasets;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import sc2pdf.javabeans.DataObject;

public class DailyDataSet {

    private Date day;
    private Collection<DataObject> data;

    public DailyDataSet() {

        this(new Date());

    }

    public DailyDataSet(Date d) {

        this.day=d;
        this.data = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

    }

    public void addDataObject(Date d, double k) {

        this.data.add(new DataObject(d,k));

    }

    public void addDataObject(DataObject d) {

        this.data.add(d);

    }

    public Date getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public Collection<DataObject> getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public DataObject getDataObject(Date toSearch) {

        Iterator<DataObject> iter = data.iterator();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(toSearch);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            DataObject dob = iter.next();
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.setTime(dob.getTimeAsDate());
            if(c.equals(c2)) {
                return dob;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    public DataObject getDataObjectByWeekday(Date toSearch) {

        Iterator<DataObject> iter = data.iterator();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(toSearch);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            DataObject dob = iter.next();
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.setTime(dob.getTimeAsDate());
            if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
                if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                    if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
                        return dob;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

## DataObject:

```
package sc2pdf.javabeans;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DataObject {

    private Date timeAsDate;
    private Integer day;
    private String timeAsString;
    private double kwh;
    private Integer type;

    public static final Integer TYPE_DATA = 1;
    public static final Integer TYPE_MIN = 2;
    public static final Integer TYPE_AVG = 3;
    public static final Integer TYPE_MAX = 4;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DataObject() {
        this(new Date(),0);
    }

    public DataObject(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int minute, double k) {

        this(day,month,year,hour,minute,k,TYPE_DATA);

    }
    public DataObject(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int minute, double k, Integer typ) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year,month,day,hour,minute);

        this.day=new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        this.timeAsDate=c.getTime();
        this.kwh=k;
        this.type=typ;

        generateTimeAsString();
    }

    public DataObject(Date t, double p) {
        this(t,p,TYPE_DATA);
    }

    public DataObject(Date t, double p, Integer ty) {

        this.timeAsDate=t;
        this.kwh=p;
        this.type=ty;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(t);

        this.day=new Integer(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        generateTimeAsString();

    }

    public void generateTimeAsString() {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(timeAsDate);
        timeAsString = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +
                        ":"+
                        c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    }

    public String getTime() {
        return timeAsString != null?timeAsString:"WRONG STRING";
    }

    public void setTime(String s) {
        this.timeAsString = s;
    }

    public Integer getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(Integer day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public double getKwh() {
        return kwh;
    }

    public void setKwh(double kwh) {
        this.kwh = kwh;
    }

    public Date getTimeAsDate() {
        return timeAsDate;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return (type.equals(DataObject.TYPE_DATA)?"DATA: ":(type.equals(DataObject.TYPE_MIN)?" MIN: ":(type.equals(DataObject.TYPE_AVG)?" AVG: ":" MAX: ")))+this.timeAsDate.toString()+": "+this.kwh;

    }

}
```

## the data as it get delivered to the report (format: [type==1?"DATA: ":type==2?"MIN: ":type==3?"AVG: ":"MAX: "]+Date+kWh

```
DATA: Tue Jan 01 00:00:07 CET 2019: 2.501
DATA: Tue Jan 01 00:15:07 CET 2019: 2.679
DATA: Tue Jan 01 00:30:07 CET 2019: 2.93
DATA: Tue Jan 01 00:45:07 CET 2019: 2.363
DATA: Tue Jan 01 01:00:07 CET 2019: 2.589
DATA: Tue Jan 01 01:15:07 CET 2019: 2.423
DATA: Tue Jan 01 01:30:07 CET 2019: 2.531
DATA: Tue Jan 01 01:45:07 CET 2019: 2.976
DATA: Tue Jan 01 02:00:07 CET 2019: 2.369
DATA: Tue Jan 01 02:15:07 CET 2019: 2.636
DATA: Tue Jan 01 02:30:07 CET 2019: 2.391
DATA: Tue Jan 01 02:45:07 CET 2019: 2.667
DATA: Tue Jan 01 03:00:07 CET 2019: 2.88
DATA: Tue Jan 01 03:15:07 CET 2019: 2.378
DATA: Tue Jan 01 03:30:07 CET 2019: 2.723
DATA: Tue Jan 01 03:45:07 CET 2019: 2.511
DATA: Tue Jan 01 04:00:07 CET 2019: 2.789
DATA: Tue Jan 01 04:15:07 CET 2019: 2.867
DATA: Tue Jan 01 04:30:07 CET 2019: 3.101
DATA: Tue Jan 01 04:45:07 CET 2019: 3.321
DATA: Tue Jan 01 05:00:07 CET 2019: 2.438
DATA: Tue Jan 01 05:15:07 CET 2019: 2.616
DATA: Tue Jan 01 05:30:07 CET 2019: 3.146
DATA: Tue Jan 01 05:45:07 CET 2019: 5.882
DATA: Tue Jan 01 06:00:07 CET 2019: 4.814
DATA: Tue Jan 01 06:15:07 CET 2019: 4.593
DATA: Tue Jan 01 06:30:07 CET 2019: 5.078
DATA: Tue Jan 01 06:45:07 CET 2019: 5.69
DATA: Tue Jan 01 07:00:07 CET 2019: 9.734
DATA: Tue Jan 01 07:15:07 CET 2019: 12.63
DATA: Tue Jan 01 07:30:07 CET 2019: 14.304
DATA: Tue Jan 01 07:45:07 CET 2019: 14.52
DATA: Tue Jan 01 08:00:07 CET 2019: 14.988
DATA: Tue Jan 01 08:15:07 CET 2019: 14.984
DATA: Tue Jan 01 08:30:07 CET 2019: 14.748
DATA: Tue Jan 01 08:45:07 CET 2019: 13.859
DATA: Tue Jan 01 09:00:07 CET 2019: 12.038
DATA: Tue Jan 01 09:15:07 CET 2019: 15.084
DATA: Tue Jan 01 09:30:07 CET 2019: 14.787
DATA: Tue Jan 01 09:45:07 CET 2019: 15.069
DATA: Tue Jan 01 10:00:07 CET 2019: 15.764
DATA: Tue Jan 01 10:15:07 CET 2019: 16.71
DATA: Tue Jan 01 10:30:07 CET 2019: 15.549
DATA: Tue Jan 01 10:45:07 CET 2019: 14.21
DATA: Tue Jan 01 11:00:07 CET 2019: 14.073
DATA: Tue Jan 01 11:15:07 CET 2019: 12.233
DATA: Tue Jan 01 11:30:07 CET 2019: 13.17
DATA: Tue Jan 01 11:45:07 CET 2019: 11.973
DATA: Tue Jan 01 12:00:07 CET 2019: 11.982
DATA: Tue Jan 01 12:15:07 CET 2019: 10.907
DATA: Tue Jan 01 12:30:07 CET 2019: 8.087
DATA: Tue Jan 01 12:45:07 CET 2019: 4.575
DATA: Tue Jan 01 13:00:07 CET 2019: 2.96
DATA: Tue Jan 01 13:15:07 CET 2019: 1.884
DATA: Tue Jan 01 13:30:07 CET 2019: 0.995
DATA: Tue Jan 01 13:45:07 CET 2019: 2.691
DATA: Tue Jan 01 14:00:07 CET 2019: 1.826
DATA: Tue Jan 01 14:15:07 CET 2019: 2.487
DATA: Tue Jan 01 14:30:07 CET 2019: 2.984
DATA: Tue Jan 01 14:45:07 CET 2019: 2.808
DATA: Tue Jan 01 15:00:07 CET 2019: 3.539
DATA: Tue Jan 01 15:15:07 CET 2019: 2.49
DATA: Tue Jan 01 15:30:07 CET 2019: 3.473
DATA: Tue Jan 01 15:45:07 CET 2019: 6.41
DATA: Tue Jan 01 16:00:07 CET 2019: 6.977
DATA: Tue Jan 01 16:15:07 CET 2019: 6.854
DATA: Tue Jan 01 16:30:07 CET 2019: 12.807
DATA: Tue Jan 01 16:45:07 CET 2019: 10.83
DATA: Tue Jan 01 17:00:07 CET 2019: 8.435
DATA: Tue Jan 01 17:15:07 CET 2019: 8.633
DATA: Tue Jan 01 17:30:07 CET 2019: 4.887
DATA: Tue Jan 01 17:45:07 CET 2019: 3.594
DATA: Tue Jan 01 18:00:07 CET 2019: 3.36
DATA: Tue Jan 01 18:15:07 CET 2019: 4.145
DATA: Tue Jan 01 18:30:07 CET 2019: 9.11
DATA: Tue Jan 01 18:45:07 CET 2019: 8.714
DATA: Tue Jan 01 19:00:07 CET 2019: 7.982
DATA: Tue Jan 01 19:15:07 CET 2019: 6.545
DATA: Tue Jan 01 19:30:07 CET 2019: 6.764
DATA: Tue Jan 01 19:45:07 CET 2019: 7.394
DATA: Tue Jan 01 20:00:07 CET 2019: 9.887
DATA: Tue Jan 01 20:15:07 CET 2019: 7.292
DATA: Tue Jan 01 20:30:07 CET 2019: 5.972
DATA: Tue Jan 01 20:45:07 CET 2019: 6.924
DATA: Tue Jan 01 21:00:07 CET 2019: 6.426
DATA: Tue Jan 01 21:15:07 CET 2019: 5.675
DATA: Tue Jan 01 21:30:07 CET 2019: 5.973
DATA: Tue Jan 01 21:45:07 CET 2019: 5.936
DATA: Tue Jan 01 22:00:07 CET 2019: 6.06
DATA: Tue Jan 01 22:15:07 CET 2019: 5.646
DATA: Tue Jan 01 22:30:07 CET 2019: 4.484
DATA: Tue Jan 01 22:45:07 CET 2019: 2.481
DATA: Tue Jan 01 23:00:07 CET 2019: 2.49
DATA: Tue Jan 01 23:15:07 CET 2019: 2.423
DATA: Tue Jan 01 23:30:07 CET 2019: 2.49
DATA: Tue Jan 01 23:45:07 CET 2019: 2.955
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 00:00:07 CET 2019: 2.154
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 00:15:07 CET 2019: 2.093
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 00:30:07 CET 2019: 2.052
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 00:45:07 CET 2019: 2.126
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 01:00:07 CET 2019: 2.139
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 01:15:07 CET 2019: 2.171
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 01:30:07 CET 2019: 2.162
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 01:45:07 CET 2019: 2.178
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 02:00:07 CET 2019: 2.049
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 02:15:07 CET 2019: 2.033
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 02:30:07 CET 2019: 2.034
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 02:45:07 CET 2019: 2.129
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 03:00:07 CET 2019: 2.159
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 03:15:07 CET 2019: 2.165
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 03:30:07 CET 2019: 2.001
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 03:45:07 CET 2019: 2.006
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 04:00:07 CET 2019: 2.313
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 04:15:07 CET 2019: 1.992
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 04:30:07 CET 2019: 2.082
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 04:45:07 CET 2019: 1.982
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 05:00:07 CET 2019: 2.217
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 05:15:07 CET 2019: 2.088
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 05:30:07 CET 2019: 2.09
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 05:45:07 CET 2019: 1.923
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 06:00:07 CET 2019: 1.928
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 06:15:07 CET 2019: 2.337
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 06:30:07 CET 2019: 2.333
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 06:45:07 CET 2019: 2.397
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 07:00:07 CET 2019: 2.135
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 07:15:07 CET 2019: 2.45
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 07:30:07 CET 2019: 2.288
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 07:45:07 CET 2019: 2.405
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 08:00:07 CET 2019: 2.093
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 08:15:07 CET 2019: 2.403
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 08:30:07 CET 2019: 3.309
 MIN: Tue Jan 01 08:45:07 CET 2019: 2.904
```

## and a screenshot from my output:

[my pdf looks like this atm...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmQJh.png)

## dummy cvs(separated by '|') valueset:

```
day|type|time|kwh
1|1|00:15|0.9
1|1|00:30|1.2
1|2|00:15|0.8
1|2|00:30|1
1|3|00:15|0.8
1|3|00:30|1.1
1|4|00:15|1
1|4|00:30|1.5
2|1|00:15|0.7
2|1|00:30|1
2|2|00:15|0.6
2|2|00:30|0.9
2|3|00:15|0.7
2|3|00:30|1
2|4|00:15|0.8
2|4|00:30|1.1
```

## expected outcome (the red line would be data of type '1', the green of type'2', the blue of type'3' and the yellow of type'4'; there should be as many charts, as different days (which would be solved via grouping, which already works):

[expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDKE9.png)

Comment: This is to much for us to check all, I think if you create a [mcve] it's easier for us to answer. We would need an example of your data source in for example cvs format (5 rows, your columns, your values), the current jrxml (already included), the current result (already included) the expected outcome.

Comment: If you can remove all from servlet and downwards only provide us with example of data you use. Hence debug to check that all that works and only give the actual data provided to jasper-reports.

Comment: not an easy task to extract those things, but i'll have a try:

Comment: ok, I will test with cvs data set that you added and your jrxml, assuming that all backing stuff is ok.

Comment: thx. i know, that the data get's to the report, as i've already tested this via placing textfields with the data in it on the report (which gets displayed flawless)

Comment: ou like 1 chart for every day, with 4 lines?

Comment: yes. each day should have one chart (on a separate page if possible), that shows four lines: the actual data for this day (type'1'), the min data (type'2'), the average data (type'3') and the max data (type'4')

Comment: hold on... i got it working....somewhat working :D replaced the incrementtype from group to none on the chart. now it displays all the data, except the min,average,max values only appear on the first seven days due to the grouping based on the day field which is a problem of my architecture...let's say fixed with the change to the right increment type ;)
can be marked as fixed/closed. thx for the help ;)

Comment: ok np, if you have problem ping me again my result was this with your data (on same page for screenshot reasons) http://i.stack.imgur.com/hATg5.png

Comment: sorry, i can't find any possibility to ping you no matter what... searching for an hour now. if you could contact me in any way, Petter, would be highly appreciated. I would have some further questions, which i think are easy to answer and not really a new question worth.

Comment: You need 20 reputation and then you can find me in chat :). Put your questions down in a comment and I will try to answer you tomorrow morning (CET)

Comment: 20 reputation...well i'll work on that. thanks for the hint ;) regarding my questions: a) how can i fix the range of the y-axis in jrxmls? as i have all my charts now working, it bothers me, that every chart comes with it's own scaling range on the y-axis. there surely is a property to set, but i just can't find anything on this issue on the interwebs. just how to do that with html5 charts and java coding....i think there is a solution with just the jrxmls. and b) how can i set the x-axis to just show every fifth or so time? here also, no info found for a fix with the jrxmls on it's own.

Comment: You can set some some properties read http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.integer.unit, if you like full control you need to develop a [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html) and set it to chart. For html5 charts you need to use another component see this https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/simple-html5-charts.

Comment: thx for the hint. i've already spotted this property, but i don't get it how to implement. do i use a tag like this:
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.count" value="30.0"/>
if so, where do i have to put that in my jrxmls? and what type does the value have to be? int? double? sorry if i have to bother you, but documentation is very rare on this topic (or at least i can't find it). I've also read about the customizer option by implementing the proper interface but i think it should be basic to set a max value to the axis, so i hope i can do that with the jrxmls only

Comment: The scope is indicated as chart (open advanced properties in chart and add property). The value is probably an int hence 30, but that is the tick count not the actual max value, I'm not sure if you can control max value of the axis only by setting this and the interval, you will have to test that by yourself. I often revert back to customizer since that way I can easily control all settings of the jfreechart.